# three.js - Reflection on ground / floor

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I would like to do same thing as that : (whithout replicate spheres)

http://people.mozilla.org/~sicking/webgl/ray.html

I made that, it works but reflections are too big :/

```
var groundTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "files/checkerboard.jpg" );
groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
groundTexture.repeat.set( 25, 25 );
groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;

mirrorGroundCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.1, 5000, 512 );
scene.add( mirrorGroundCamera );

var mirrorGroundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: groundTexture,  side: THREE.DoubleSide, envMap: mirrorGroundCamera.renderTarget } );
mirrorGround = new THREE.Mesh( groundGeometry, mirrorGroundMaterial );
mirrorGround.position.y = -0.5;
mirrorGround.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
mirrorGroundCamera.position = mirrorGround.position;
scene.add(mirrorGround);
```

Answer (score 1):

Environment mapping in three.js is an approximation, and makes the assumption that the environment is "infinitely" far away.

See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html for an example of how to handle mirror reflections in three.js.

three.js r.70